# access the length of list from inside a method

Tags: python, list

I am a little confused about this one. In one of my scripts i have the following method.

```
ALIVES = []


def insert_in_alives(num):
    ALIVES.append(num)
    print len(ALIVES), "alives found."
```

Here ALIVES is just a list declared outside the method. But whenever the `update_alives` method is called it always print the following, No matter what the actual length of `ALIVES` is.

```
>>>1 alives found.
```

Can somebody tell me why is it doing so ?

UPDATE:

tried it in the shell and it works:

```
In [2]: a = [1,2,3]

In [3]: print len(a)
3
In [4]: def test(num):
   ...:     a.append(num)
   ...:     print len(a)
   ...:     

In [5]: test(5)
4

In [6]: test(7)
5
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? There is no problem with your snippet that would result in the situation you have described.

Comment: I think you need to show us more code. Your example code will print `2 alives found` the second time you call it.

Comment: yeah, i tried it in the shell and it works fine (see update), but not in the script, why would that be ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Hey i have added the link to the script in the last update. Thanks.

Comment: @Amyth: looking now; better to add code to your question though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Added the code to the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things are wrong:

- Your `_get_data` function returns an empty string if the URL you requested returned an empty response. Thus, your `proxy_alive()` function won't call `insert_in_alives()` either.

  Change `proxy_alive()` to test for `None` instead:

  ```
  def proxy_alive(proxy):
      test = _get_data('http://m.naukri.com', proxy=proxy, silent=True)
      if test is not None:
          insert_in_alives(proxy)
  ```
- You are checking for proxies in a thread, and each thread is calling `insert_in_alives()` *at the same time*. This is causing a race condition, the inserts are replacing one another.

  You'll need to add a thread lock there.

Comment: tried but it still returns 1 for the length, i added `print(len(ALIVES))` in the `insert_in_alives()` methods and the response was >> found 100 proxies

Removed 78 duplicates ..
checking (22) proxies, Please wait ... 
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: @Amyth: *Nothing* in that code you shared resets the list. Something is missing here.

Comment: @Amyth: ah, missed you are using threads. You have a race condition.

Comment: Ahh damn, True that, as soon as i set multiprocessing to `False` it works. Thanks buddy !

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine.

```py
ALIVES = []


def update_alives(num):
    ALIVES.append(num)
    print ALIVES
    print len(ALIVES), "alives found."


update_alives(3)
update_alives(5)
update_alives(6)
```

If I do this, I add a 3 to the list, which results in one element in it.

If i do that more than once, you append to the list, increasing it.

Output:

```
[3]
1 alives found.
[3, 5]
2 alives found.
[3, 5, 6]
3 alives found.
```

Comment: My answer is not correct with the additional source code added to the question.